# SQL: Right way to model multible relations in UML/ ERD

Tags: sql, uml, erd

How do I do the `UML` for the this example:

```
Order(ID, user_id, invoice_user_id) where user_id and invoice_user_id are foreign keys and user_id != null
```

Both users stored in the same entity. How are the cardinalities or the `UML` priciple? I guessed it that way:

`[Order]0..n--1..2[User]`

so an order can have 2 users. Another option (I hope you understand my textpicture...)
This should mean that an order can have up to 2 Users. Or is this way right:

`[Order]n -- 1[User]
   |n
   |1
 [(Invoice)User]`

One user can have many orders and/or can be the invoice user of many orders...

Answer (score 1):

You should be naming your unnamed association-end properties and using two separate associations. The way you have it, there is no way to get to the `Invoice User` separately from the other `User`. And what are these users anyway? You probably need to do more analysis to understand the roles involved. Here's my guess:

- Seller *creates* any number of Invoices
- Buyer *receives* any number of Invoices
- Invoice *received by* one Buyer
- Invoice *created by* one Seller

That gives you a model like this:

```
 ------
|Seller|
 ------
 1 | creatingSeller
   |
 * | createdInvoice
 -------  *                              1  -----
|Invoice|----------------------------------|Buyer|
 -------  receivedInvoice   receivingBuyer  -----
```

Now you can navigate to the two "users".

BTW, both `Buyer` and `Seller` are likely roles played by an agent, like a `Person` or an `Organization`. I'm not going to model the whole thing for you.

Just so you are aware, there are other ways to realize this model in an RDBMS, using "reference data" / "enumeration literals" to differentiate the two associations and the two roles of agent. Your original question indicates you want a more physical model, but I think you're asking for trouble by skipping the analysis model, which can be realized as it is in an RDBMS.

Comment: My intention was that an Order is associated with an user for getting the goods, and/ or an user for getting the invoice. If no invoice user is set, the `delivery_user` is getting the invoice. In this case I didn't want to save the invoice in DB. There will only be one Invoice for an order and the order number is the same as the Invoice number.

Is this way of thinking wrong?
I think I haven't got your answer right yet...

I would now replace the `Invoice` of your picture with my `Order`, the `Seller` with `Payor` and rename the association-end properties as well.